# How does Intersystems cache recall the covered code

Tags: caching, m, intersystems, cls, intersystems-iris

I drag my `.cls` file to Intersystems studio, the old version code covered my latest version code, is there any way to get back my covered cls file ?

Answer (score 1):

InterSystems Caché/IRIS stores most of the code right in the Database, and Database by default is journaled. So, you can revert your code by those journals. But unfortunately, it is not so easy to explain how to do it.

Comment: Do you have any document about how to revert class files by journals?  Thank you anyway~

Comment: No, it is just only for experienced users, who can manage it. There is some API for Journals, which may help. https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYS.Journal.File